# Getting line number information in the Semantic Analysis Phase (using Alex,Happy)

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, happy, alex

I am doing semantic analysis for an experimental language. I am using Alex and Happy to generate the lexer and the parser (actually I am using BNFC tool to generate Alex and Happy files). I wanted to get an error message with the line number and the column number whenever there is a  semantic error, say, a type error.

**It seems that I would have to store the line number information while building my symbol table or the AST. My problem would would be solved if I can somehow have access to the position information in the the rules sections of the Happy file.**

Any suggestions in this regard would be highly appreciated.

I tried implementing the answer suggested below but unfortunately have not had any success with this. Lets consider for a very simple grammar :-

```
Expr -> Expr + Term
       | Term
Term -> Int
```

My lexer for this looks like below.

```
%wrapper "posn"

$digit = 0-9            -- digits
$alpha = [a-zA-Z]       -- alphabetic characters

tokens :-

  $white+               ;
  "--".*                ;
  $digit+               { \p s -> L {getPos = p , unPos = Tok_Int (read s) }}
  \+                    { \p s -> L {getPos = p , unPos = Tok_Plus} }


{
data L a = L{ getPos :: AlexPosn, unPos :: a } deriving (Eq,Show)

data Token =
      Tok_Plus 
    | Tok_Int Int 
    deriving (Eq,Show)


getToken :: IO [L Token]
getToken = do 
    args <- getArgs
    case length args == 0 of
        True  -> do 
               error $ "\n****************Error: Expecting file name as an argument.\n" 
        False -> do
            let fname  = args !! 0 
            conts <- readFile fname
            let tokens = alexScanTokens conts 
            return tokens 

}
```

My Yacc file is as under and this is where I am struggling. How to embed the position information in my syntax tree.

```
{
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-incomplete-patterns -fno-warn-overlapping-patterns #-}
module Parser where
import Lexer

}

%name pExpr Exp 
%name pTerm Term 

%tokentype {L Token}
%error { parseError }

%token
      int             { L { getPos = _,unPos = Tok_Int $$ } }
      '+'             { L { getPos = _,unPos = Tok_Plus } }

%%
Exp :: {L Expr} 
Exp  : Exp '+' Term           { L { getPos =  getPos $1 , unPos = EAdd (unPos $1) (unPos $3) } }
     | Term                   { $1 }

Term :: {L Expr}
Term : int                   { L {getPos =  getPos $1, unPos =  EInt (unPos $1) } } 

{

data Expr =  EAdd Expr Expr 
            | EInt Int 
            deriving (Eq,Show)


returnM :: a -> Err a
returnM = return

thenM :: Err a -> (a -> Err b) -> Err b
thenM = (>>=)


parseError :: [L Token] -> a
parseError _ = error "Parse error"

}
```

I get the following type errors when trying to compile the generated Haskell file.

```
Parser.hs:109:39:
    Couldn't match expected type `L a0' with actual type `Int'
    In the first argument of `getPos', namely `happy_var_1'
    In the `getPos' field of a record
    In the first argument of `HappyAbsSyn5', namely
      `(L {getPos = getPos happy_var_1,
           unPos = EInt (unPos happy_var_1)})'

Parser.hs:109:73:
    Couldn't match expected type `L Int' with actual type `Int'
    In the first argument of `unPos', namely `happy_var_1'
    In the first argument of `EInt', namely `(unPos happy_var_1)'
    In the `unPos' field of a record
```

**Can you guys suggest me how to get this thing working?**

Answer (score 6):

You can have access to the position information in a Happy rule, if they are available in your lexer output. This is exactly how e.g. GHC itself puts `SrcLoc`s into its own internal representation of Haskell code.

Basically, you would use [the `posn` Alex wrapper](https://www.haskell.org/alex/doc/html/wrappers.html#id462357) to inject position information into your token type:

```
data L a = L{ getPos :: AlexPosn, unPos :: a }
```

(so your Alex tokenizer would return `L Token` values); and then you combine the individual token positions in your Happy rule into a position for the nonterminal (so you could, for example, have a rule from `Expr + Expr` to `L (combinedPosn [getPos $1, getPos $2, getPos $3] $ PlusExpr (unPos $1) (unPos $3)`.